# problema con lista de opciones en html

Tags: select

estoy realizando una lista de opciones y he usado la etiqueta select y el atributo size, el problema es que en la pc se muestra bien pero en el mobil no.

estaba pensando en susutiturilo po un menu, pero estoy manejando el atributo value para guardar las id que se recuperan de la bd,

¿ay alguna forma de que el select se vizualice bien en el mobil? 
u otra alternativa que pueda usar para hacer una lista de opciones que me permita manejar algo similar al atributo value

espero y me puedan ayudar

Comment: Has probado con la librerias de bootstrap para el responsive design?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo hay, en tu css o en el documento html deberias poner lo siguiente:

```
#idDeTuComponente {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: anchoquequieras; //ej.(1920 px)
    max-height: alturaquequieras;
 }
```

De esta forma lo que hará el css será asignar el máximo de tamaño posible al componente dependiendo de la pantalla,(recomiendo usar 'div') y de máximo le asignara la grandaria de tu pantalla o la que le quieras dar al componente, así que nunca pasará de ese tamaño pero se regulará si es menor a esta

Comment: gracias po la ayuda, disculpa, al iddecomponente se refiere al contenedor donde esta el select? por que el select esta dentro un div que contiene el form y el select

Comment: @OliverPeres si no me equivoco sin probarlos, creo que da igual si se lo pones al contenedor del select o al mismo select, pero haz la prueba

Comment: ok gracias lo revisare

Comment: @OliverPeres si, el id debe ser del contenedor o del elemento si no está dentro de ninguno